# Права доступа, WinSCP

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В общем проблема началась с того что я методом тыка установил phpmyadmin на linux. После этого я открыл его через браузер и попробовал зайти с чистым логином/паролем(root/'') и мне сразу же выдало ошибку.

Я почитал и нашел что нужно указать юзера/пароль для него в конфиг файле config.inc.php. Я задал и решил загрузить файл обратно на сервер с помощью WinSCP и получил ошибку:

```
Доступ запрещён.
Код ошибки: 3
Сообщение ошибки от сервер: Permission denied
```

Затем я зашел в настройки подключения - sftp и выбрал вариант "sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server" для доступа к правам root(верно же?). И это не дало никакого результата. Что еще нужно что бы пользоваться FTP менеджерами для полного доступа к файлам?

П.С. через консоль все работает, но не закачивать/редактировать же файлы через нее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В FAQ WinSCP есть заметка по этой теме:
[How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)
Обратите внимание на следующее:

1. Нужно убедиться, что путь к `sftp-server` верный (например, на моей машине он выглядит так: `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`)
2. Поскольку через WinSCP вы не можете передать пароль команде `su`, то нужно обеспечить выполнение команды без ввода пароля. Для этого в файл `/etc/sudoers` добавить строку:

   `yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

   либо с ограничением только для SFTP сессий:

   `yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/sftp-server` (путь такой же как и в п.1)

Авторы так же предупреждают, что это несет определенные риски, затрагивающие безопасность сервера.

Comment: Слушайте, для начала, нет ли способа попроще получить полный доступ? Мне это нужно единоразово, я не хотел бы сейчас тратить время на углубление в этом вопросе.. Так же я не понимаю что за путь к sftp, я думал доступ сразу ко всей системе можно получить просто войдя в юзера с root правами. И последнее: та строка отвеняет пароль на учетке или что это? Мне нельзя снимать пароль с аккаунта, иначе он станет уязвимым..

Comment: @Levelleor 1) путь к бинарнику sftp-server, который и позволяет вам заливать/качать файлы (по аналогии с FTP-сервером Windows). 2) указанные строки в /etc/sudoers пароль не отменяют. При логине на сервере пароль будет запрашиваться в любом случае, но при получении прав суперпользователя командой `su` пароль не запросится. 3) если вам нужно единоразово что-то залить - заливайте файлы в tmp и командами через терминал перемещайте/копируйте куда нужно с правами суперпользователя. Для правки конфигов можете юзать редакторы, например,  **nano** или **vim**.

Comment: Я все эти консольные варианты уже перепробовал, это было ужасно... Спасибо, пойду проверю.

Answer (score 0):

делается просто

в настройках подключение WinSCP 
нажимаем на кнопку "Еще"
далее SCP/оболочка 
в "Командная оболочка": выбираем sudo su-